# MTG: Balthor the Defiled as a Commander

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

[Balthor the Defiled](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBalthor%20the%20Defiled%5d) has an activated ability with the cost "Remove Balthor the Defiled from the game". Excusing that this is now called exile, if Balthor was your commander, could you have Balthor go to your command zone instead of exile and still fulfill the cost for the ability?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. I found it useful to tag cards with "[MTG:*Card Name*]" when quoting cards. It gives you a link direct to the gatherer.

Comment: No they don't. They have an ability with the cost "{B}{B}{B}, Exile Balthor the Defiled". There hasn't been such thing as "remove from the game" for over 15 years now. Make sure to consult [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=20842) for the text of your cards.

Comment: @ikegami the "printed" text on gatherer does say remove from the game.

Comment: @ThunderToes, What's your point? Did you incorrectly think you contradicted what I said? What I said stands: Contrary to what the OP said, Balthor the Defiled doesn't have an activated ability with the cost "Remove Balthor the Defiled from the game". Its text was changed over 15 years ago.

Comment: @ikegami I just thought it wasn't all that important. plus mentioning that it specifically states that on gatherer is not strictly true as when you open the card link the text on the card image is Remove from game. I think most MTG players will know that means exile by now.

Comment: @ThunderToes, What are you talking about? I never said it's nowhere in Gatherer. Don't tell me I'm wrong for saying things I didn't even say! /// Re "*I just thought it wasn't all that important.*", Not so! Telling people that only the Oracle text matters is of the uttermost importance. One should NEVER rely on the printed text.

Comment: First off I never said you were wrong. Secondly you have misread my second comment. You said check gatherer for the wordings. checking gatherer shows the card with "Remove from Game". So you cant realy justify saying the OP is wrong when you are telling them to check gatherer while gatherer shows the original printed text. I feel the comment was slightly pedantic. I did not say whether it was correct or not.

Comment: @ThunderToes, You are wrong. Gatherer does not say "Remove from Game" in the card's text. Just stop with the misinformation! Or maybe you think the OP is too dumb to realize that "card text" and "card's text" are synonymous even after being quoted the "card text" as being the "card's text"? Either way, not kosher! Your comments are not useful; harmful even.

Comment: @ikegami whatever dude you are blowing this out of all proportion. You never mentioned Oracle text in your first comment you just said check gatherer for text. I'm not going to squabble with you over a pedantic matter such as this.

Comment: @ThunderToes, Re "*You never mentioned Oracle text in your first comment*", Duh! There's no mention of "Oracle text" on the Gatherer page either!!! Please just stop!!! Enough with the nonsense!

Comment: @ikegami there is an "Oracle" Tab and a "Printed" Tab the Oracle tab card text states Exile and the printed tab card text states Remove from the game. you did not distinguish between these when directing the OP to Gatherer. but you are outright refusing to see this point through pride maybe.

Comment: @ThunderToes, Neat. 1) I didn't know that existed, and 2) I didn't link to the "printed" page, and neither do searches of Gatherer. 3) Again, it's not kosher to treat the OP as too dumb to realize I'm taking about the field that says "{B}{B}{B}, Exile Balthor the Defiled" when I say it says "{B}{B}{B}, Exile Balthor the Defiled". Please just stop!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76829/discussion-between-thundertoes-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 8):

**You sure can.** 903.9 says anytime a commander goes into exile, the graveyard, hand, or library from anywhere; you can instead put them into the command zone. This will, however, increase the cost to play them by (2) every time you do this, which is known as Commander Tax. E.g. First cast of Balthor from the command zone will cost the base of 2BB, 2nd time will be 4BB, 3rd time 6BB, etc.

Also, for older cards, make sure to check the oracle text on your card-viewing site of choice if the wording is confusing. (Gatherer is the official Wizards card-viewer.)